# How to add width to textarea in TextField from material ui with styled-components

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, textfield, styled-components

How can I add a `width` to a `textarea` in `TextField` from material-ui and styled-components?

I'm talking about the actual text input where users can type text.

Is there any way to add the width to it?

```
import * as React from "react";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import { StyledTextField } from "./styles";

export default function BasicTextFields() {
  return (
    <Box component="form">
      <StyledTextField
        id="outlined-basic"
        label="Outlined"
        variant="outlined"
      />
    </Box>
  );
}
```

```
import styled from "styled-components";
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";

export const StyledTextField = styled(TextField)`
  width: 400px;
`;

StyledTextField.displayName = "StyledTextField";
```

Answer (score 0):

use **sx** prop

```
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";

<TextField 
  id="outlined-basic"
  label="Outlined"
  variant="outlined"
  sx={{
    width: 400px;
  }}
/>
```

Comment: I'm not talking about the whole width of TextField. I'd like to apply the width to textarea